# How to set an image in service (outside the activity) in android

Tags: android, service, android-imageview

I want to implement an application that shows an image on the screen even if the user closes activity(application). I know that this kind of implementation only can be done through services in android.

Can you help me about how to implement drawing an ImageView on a service. If someone can give me an idea, I will appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Directly show an Image from Service. But what you can do is have an Activity to Display the Image.

When you want to display the image just start the Activity containing the Image.